# Embedding a button in a grid causes the grid to behave as the button?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script to build a web app, when I put a button widget in a grid widget, it seems the entire grid turns into the "button".

i.e. if I put:

```
var myGrid = app.createGrid(4,4);
var addButton = myGrid.setWidget(3,3,app.createButton("Add"));
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('add');
addButton.addClickHandler(handler);
app.add(myGrid);
```

In the resulting web app if I click anywhere on the grid the clickhandler for the button fires.  Even worse, if I embed multiple buttons in the grid, clicking anywhere on the grid fires all button clickhandlers.

Are buttons in grids not supported?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Edit:  If you want to see the behaviour for yourself, I've replicated the issue by modifying one of Google's examples.  The second example for "Validators" here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#Validators I modified and put the textboxes and the button in a Grid Widget.  After entering numbers in the text boxes, every time you click anywhere on the grid the "add" clickhandler will fire and add the numbers again:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var rgx = "^\\$?[0-9]+$";

  // Create input boxes and button.

  //var textBoxA = app.createTextBox().setId('textBoxA').setName('textBoxA');
  //var textBoxB = app.createTextBox().setId('textBoxB').setName('textBoxB');
  var myGrid = app.createGrid(4,4);
  myGrid.setWidget(0,0,app.createTextBox().setId('textBoxA').setName('textBoxA'));
  myGrid.setWidget(0,1,app.createTextBox().setId('textBoxB').setName('textBoxB'));

  var textBoxA = app.getElementById('textBoxA');
  var textBoxB = app.getElementById('textBoxB');

  var addButton = myGrid.setWidget(3,3,app.createButton("Add").setEnabled(false));
  var label = app.createLabel("Please input two numbers");

  // Create a handler to call the adding function.
  // Two validations are added to this handler so that it will
  // only invoke 'add' if both textBoxA and textBoxB contain
  // numbers.
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('add').validateMatches(textBoxA,rgx).validateMatches(textBoxBrgx).addCallbackElement(textBoxA).addCallbackElement(textBoxB);

  // Create a handler to enable the button if all input is legal
  var onValidInput = app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(textBoxA,rgx).validateMatches(textBoxB,rgx).forTargets(addButton).setEnabled(true).forTargets(label).setVisible(false);

  // Create a handler to mark invalid input in textBoxA and disable the button
  var onInvalidInput1 = app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(textBoxA,rgx).forTargets(addButton).setEnabled (false).forTargets(textBoxA).setStyleAttribute("color",     "red").forTargets(label).setVisible(true);

   // Create a handler to mark the input in textBoxA as valid
  var onValidInput1 =     app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(textBoxA,rgx).forTargets(textBoxA).setStyleAttribute("color", "black");

   // Create a handler to mark invalid input in textBoxB and disable the button
  var onInvalidInput2 =     app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(textBoxB,rgx).forTargets(addButton).setEnabled(false).forTargets(textBoxB).setStyleAttribute("color", "red").forTargets(label).setVisible(true);

  // Create a handler to mark the input in textBoxB as valid
  var onValidInput2 = app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(textBoxB,rgx).forTargets(textBoxB).setStyleAttribute("color","black");

  // Add all the handlers to be called when the user types in the text boxes
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onInvalidInput1);
  textBoxB.addKeyUpHandler(onInvalidInput2);
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onValidInput1);
  textBoxB.addKeyUpHandler(onValidInput2);
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onValidInput);
  textBoxB.addKeyUpHandler(onValidInput);
  addButton.addClickHandler(handler);

  app.add(myGrid);
  //app.add(textBoxB);
  //app.add(addButton);
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}

function add(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var result = parseFloat(e.parameter.textBoxA) + parseFloat(e.parameter.textBoxB);
   var newResultLabel = app.createLabel("Result is: " + result);
  app.add(newResultLabel);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

`var addButton = myGrid.setWidget(3,3,app.createButton("Add"));`

and then you add a handler to the variable `addButton` **you are in fact adding the handler to the grid, not to the button**.

I would suggest to rewrite it like this (I commented the code) and it will work normally

```
var myGrid = app.createGrid(4,4);
var addButton = app.createButton("Add");
myGrid.setWidget(3,3,addButton);// here you add the button to the grid
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('add');
addButton.addClickHandler(handler);
app.add(myGrid);// only the grid must be added, the button is already in it
```

or, if you want to make it more compact :

```
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('add');
var myGrid = app.createGrid(4,4).setWidget(3,3,createButton("Add",handler));// here you add the button to the grid
app.add(myGrid);// only the grid must be added, the button is already in it
```

Comment: Sorry, I miss-typed my example, I've corrected it in my OP.  I'd already removed the app.add(addButton) in my troubleshooting, and that did not fix the issue - the grid still behaves as the button.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I see now.  That fixed the problem I was having in the Google code example.  Issue is still happening in my own app when I make those changes, but I'm probably missing something else.  I programmed in C and Fortran 20+ years ago, and just recently dipped my toe back in.  Things seemed to have changed in the intervening years . . . .

Comment: Don't tell me.!  :-)  I was using Basic back in 1980 ... :-)

Comment: There, change worked in my original code as well after I accounted for fat fingers.  Thanks for the help.  And I can only trace back to BASIC on an Apple II+ in 1984 :)

Comment: It seem that you are not from Europe. BASIC entererd the masses in 1977 with the Commodore PET - the personal computer with the integrated audio cassette player used mass storage device.

Comment: I was the happy owner of a Sinclair ZX81 with 1k RAM and a B&W TVconnected to an ordinary cassette recorder for data saving. That said, the performances where amazing in regard to the hardware :-) ... It ended up with a Sinclair QL, a Motorola 68030 based system with floppy disks!  Almost a Rolls Royce!!